# Is it ok to store session_state in the client's local storage?

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid

I am using OpenId with Keycloak for the authentification management in a web application. I would like to use the session_state value given by Keycloak to manage session data using the OpenId definition of a session, not the browser definition. I mean I don't want to have two sessions when I log once and open my web app in two tabs.

Is it ok to store session_state in the client's browser local storage?

First I thought about the refresh token but then I read it's not recommended to store it outside a secured cookie. I don't find any similar recommandation about the session_state. session_state cannot be used to access any data right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OpenID Connect Session Management draft](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#OPiframe) the session state must be accessible by Javascript so it can be kept in local storage (the spec even says that it can be kept in local storage).